# Visual Studio Version Mainstream

Tags: visual-studio

Which is preferred in the software design world, VS2008 or VS2010. I find that I like the UI, debugger, and enhanced intellisense in VS2010; however most people on my team have not upgraded to VS2010 making it tough to convert projects back from 2010 to 2008. I almost get the impression VS2008 is preferred. Also, how long would you say it took VS2005 to disappear from the mainstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(C++ bias answer)

IMO, Visual Studio 2008 is rock solid for heavy duty c++/MFC development; we have no reason to upgrade.

If you need and want to use more modern C++ construct defined in c++0x, then you will need to update and use Visual Studio 2010.

The biggest issues with VS2010 for me, is that the UI of the IDE is very slow and heavy compared to VS2008 on the same machine, it's about 5 times slower for most operations (I can't stand waiting for a file to open).

Also they made some decisions that I do not really agree with (removed the MDI, among others)

But the compiler is doing a better job.

Max